# iPhone imported photos unable to add to icloud photos library nor export

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I have an iPhone 11 with around 3k photos, and another  ~2k photos which were imported from old iPhone 6. I started running out of storage, therefore I wanted to turn on iCloud photos, but it asks if I want to delete those old photos from iPhone 6, which I obviously don’t want to.

I tried adding them somehow to the main library, because I only see them in the albums part, but I dont see any option to do so.

Then I connected iPhone 11 to a Mac (with a different account on the Mac) and only thing I see are those photos taken with iPhone 11; there is no way I can get to the iPhone 6 photos.

The only thing I was able to do is use a Windows laptop to save photos using iTunes. Then, I turned on iCloud Photos which then finally deleted those old photos I had imported and now backed up to Windows machine.

Can anyone tell me how I am supposed to import old photos to the iCloud library so that they are backed up as intended?

Comment: Photos that are imported onto a phone from iTunes are separated. This is likely why you couldn't import them anywhere. This feature was back in the syncing days when you would never store the original media on your phone, always on your computer. It's not intended to be used today in conjunction with iCloud Photos which is why you experienced these issues.

Comment: A proper backup would be to have your files/photos in 3 separate places.  Get something like the [SanDisk iXpand Flash Drive for iPhone/iPad](http://radnex.us/Sandisk_iXpand_Flash) (I love this thing) to do a local backup.  iCloud is a *sync* service, not a backup so one minor mistake could delete your library and then sync across all your devices leaving you photo-less.  My suggesting is to get all of your photos into one place, do a iCloud sync like it was “New” then sync across all your devices.

Comment: Hi @Allan, yes you are right it’s a sync not a backup. Thanks for the advice. I got my photos backed up already I just wanted to add them to the already synced photos, which should be super easy as that’s the very reason why I switched from windows + Samsung to Mac and iphone, but this is just impossibly too much hustle for a thing that should be a no brainer simple.

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457678/119271)  I wrote not too long ago about doing this with documents.  The principle is the same get everything local, make sure you have a back up, then clean out and deactivate iCloud.  Re-enable as if it were new so the iPhone sends all photos up and not sync deletions down.

Comment: +1 to negate the down vote, too.  Not sure why it got downvoted in the first place.

Comment: @Allan thanks once again, we’ll probably because of the negative tone, I was bit mad about that topic